# OpenCV 2.3: how to capture frames from Android camera?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to use new OpenCV feature on Android: native camera access. According to [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.3.0#NativecamerasupportinOpenCV) document, it's quite easy, but I only get the error without success.

There is DDMS log:

> 08-26 03:28:56.825: DEBUG/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): Library name: libopencv_java.so
>   08-26 03:28:56.825: DEBUG/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): Library base address: 0x81800000
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: DEBUG/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): Libraries folder found: /data/data/com.viactivity.ar/lib/
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: DEBUG/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib: folderPath=/data/data/com.viactivity.ar/lib/
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: ERROR/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): ||libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: ERROR/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): ||libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: DEBUG/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): try to load library 'libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so'
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: DEBUG/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library /data/data/com.viactivity.ar/lib/libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so, dlerror="Cannot load library: find_library[1223]: 11258 'libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so' failed to load previously"
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: DEBUG/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): try to load library 'libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so'
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: DEBUG/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library /data/data/com.viactivity.ar/lib/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so, dlerror="Cannot load library: find_library[1223]: 11258 'libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so' failed to load previously"
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: ERROR/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(12613): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: ERROR/CV_CAP(12613): Native_camera returned opening error: 4
>   08-26 03:28:56.835: ERROR/AR_code(12613): Capture Error!

There are two variants of code:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANDROID + 0 ); 
IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

.

```
cv::VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_ANDROID + 0);
cv::Mat frame;

capture >> frame;
```

Both of them produce the same errors.
Does somebody was able to get native camera access on Android? 
Thanks a lot!

**UPD:** 
The story above is about Android 3.2. According to the words of  Andrey Kamaev, Android 3.2 isn't supported.
I tried to test the same code on HTC Wildfire, but got another error:

> 08-26 19:49:06.856: DEBUG/OpenCV_NativeCamera(1337):
>   CameraHandler::initCameraConnect(0x813e65a1, 0, 0x285a20, 0x0) 08-26
>   19:49:06.856: DEBUG/CameraService(72): CameraService::connect E (pid
>   1337, client 0x693d8) 08-26 19:49:06.856: DEBUG/CameraService(72):
>   CameraService::connect X (pid 1337, new client 0x693d8) rejected. (old
>   pid 1337, old client 0x18728) 08-26 19:49:06.856:
>   ERROR/OpenCV_NativeCamera(1337): initCameraConnect: Unable to connect
>   to CameraService 08-26 19:49:06.856: ERROR/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(1337):
>   CameraWrapperConnector::connectWrapper ERROR: the initializing
>   function returned false 08-26 19:49:06.856: ERROR/CV_CAP(1337):
>   Native_camera returned opening error: 6

Any ideas?

Comment: What device do you use? What version of Android?

Comment: Device: Asus EEE Pad Transformer TF101, Android 3.2. If you need to run any debug code on it, you can send me packages to vitalys@gmail.com Thanks.

Comment: For HTC: check that standard camera application is able to show preview from camera. Error 6 usually means that camera is locked by another application and you need to find that app and make it to correctly release the camera or reboot the phone.

Comment: There were a mistake in my code. I forgot to delete Camera.open method from java part. Now it works!

Comment: @VitalyS.  i have one  doubt . You can open android camera through opencv through above code . and also we can get frames  through cvQueryFrame() function... but do we need to set surfaceview to display all this frames ...?? means do we have to pass all these frames from native level to android  i am not sure....pls guide me...

Comment: @hardikpansuria, there was also an OpenGL layer in my application, so I displayed frames from camera as OpenGL background textures. Anyway, I returned to the native frames capture, because OpenCV camera access insn't increase capture rate for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment OpenCV native camera does not support Android 3.2 (because its sources are not publicly available.)

I'll post an update as soon as version compatible with Android 3.2 become available.

### Update:

OpenCV trunk already has solution for Android 3.x and 4.0.x. It will be included into the next major release of OpenCV.

Comment: Ok, I tried to test the same code on HTC Wildfire (Android 2.2.1), but got another error :(

Comment: Could you also post this error? It should work on this model of HTC.

Comment: Do you need any additional info?

Comment: I've added comment to your question. Have you the same problem after rebooting your phone?

Comment: Facing the same issue with the HTC Sensation (Android 2.3.3).

Answer (score 1):

The above two methods what u had described cannot be worked out, instead of that ...

use Camera.Preview callback to get the raw YUV frames , then convert the YUV Frames to RGB , then construct IPlImage* from the data available ,

Then use the constructed IplImage for further processing

Comment: I tried that way, but Camera.Preview performance is awful, that's why I'm looking for other solutions.