# Android OpenCV: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library

Tags: android, opencv

Similar to [OpenCV 2.3: how to capture frames from Android camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198912/opencv-2-3-how-to-capture-frames-from-android-camera)

I'm trying to get OpenCV to run on my [Samsung Fascinate](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SCH-I500RKAVZW) (v2.2.1) following [this tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html)

When I try to run the samples (like sample 15-puzzle) for instance, I get the following errors:

```
03-31 14:05:39.399: D/dalvikvm(4915): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/lib/libopencv_java.so 0x47c22ef8
03-31 14:05:39.399: D/dalvikvm(4915): Shared lib '/data/data/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/lib/libopencv_java.so' already loaded in same CL 0x47c22ef8
03-31 14:05:39.399: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): Library name: libopencv_java.so
03-31 14:05:39.399: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): Library base address: 0x81800000
03-31 14:05:39.418: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): Libraries folder found: /data/data/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/lib/
03-31 14:05:39.426: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib: folderPath=/data/data/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/lib/
03-31 14:05:39.426: E/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): ||libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so
03-31 14:05:39.426: E/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): ||libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
03-31 14:05:39.426: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): try to load library 'libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so'
03-31 14:05:39.434: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library /data/data/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/lib/libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so, dlerror="Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so
03-31 14:05:39.434: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): "
03-31 14:05:39.434: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): try to load library 'libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so'
03-31 14:05:39.434: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library /data/data/org.opencv.samples.puzzle15/lib/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so, dlerror="Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
03-31 14:05:39.434: D/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): "
03-31 14:05:39.434: E/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(4915): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library
03-31 14:05:39.434: E/CV_CAP(4915): Native_camera returned opening error: 4
03-31 14:05:39.434: E/Sample::SurfaceView(4915): Failed to open native camera
```

So the library cannot be opened. Any ideas on why? Is it not being found?

**Update**:This also happens on the emulator.

Comment: I did a quick search, but unsure what you mean. Other android applications work fine on my phone and it seems to find in while on the emulator, but not on my device (so I think it's a runtime issue)

Comment: Sorry, there was a misunderstood. My fault. Deleting previous comment. Which sdk do you have in your phone and emulator? Are they same? And did you do the step in the following post? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8016306/856702)

Comment: They are both 2.2. Not sure if the link applies since I already have the libraries on my computer. I wonder if it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so` is in `libs/`. That file should be packaged so that it can be loaded dynamically by `dlopen`.